# How to use SQL query with havng count here?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having-clause

I having Table(Tbl_Test) with following data.

```
         RecordId     BatchName         Numbers        MQC          
          1          20150443          321106          0    
          2          20150430          321107          0
          3          20150430          321107          1
          4          20150412          321110          2
          5          20150430          321118   
          6          20150430          321120   
          7          20150432          321120   
          8          20150430          321126   
          9          20150432          321127   
          10         20150430          321129
          11         20150431          321129
```

From the above table I want output like,Numbers columns whose count is greater  than 1.

```
     RecordId     BatchName         Numbers        MQC          
      2          20150430          321107          0    
      3          20150430          321107          1
      6          20150430          321120   
      7          20150432          321120   
      10         20150430          321129
      11         20150431          321129
```

I've tried the following select but without success:

```
select RecordId,BatchName,Numbers,MQC 
from Tbl_Test 
group by RecordId,BatchName,Numbers,MQC 
having count(Numbers)>1
```

Comment: You want but what have you tried? What is your rdbms?

Comment: Grouping by a unique id column is a nonsense operation. you will get the exact same result from `select id from table` and `Select id from table group by id`

Comment: I've edited your question to include your efforts. Please edit it to include a tag with your rdbms (mysql, oracle, sql server...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a [Common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).
Try this:

```
;With CTE AS
(
    SELECT Numbers,
           Count(1) As NumberOfRows
    FROM Tbl_Test 
    GROUP BY Numbers
)

SELECT T.*
FROM Tbl_Test T
INNER JOIN CTE ON(T.Numbers = CTE.Numbers)
WHERE NumberOfRows > 1
```

[play with it your self on sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88485/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    RecordId, 
    BatchName, 
    Numbers,
    MQC,
    count(*) over (partition by Numbers) cnt
  FROM tbl_test
)
SELECT 
  RecordId, BatchName, Numbers, MQC
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` and `IN`.Something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Test 
WHERE Numbers IN
(
    SELECT Numbers
    FROM Tbl_Test 
    GROUP BY Numbers
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use count on RecordID with group By on MQC.

'Count(RecordId) Group By MQC' should work for you.

Comment: how does this help the OP?